# How to display iptables forwarding rule?

Tags: iptables

I have executed following command on a EC2 instance to forward incoming port 80 traffic to port 8080:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

It didn't output anything but when I can see that forwarding actually works.

I tried to verify in the commandline but I can't figure out how:

```
$ iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

According to `iptables --help`, the `-A` option expects a chain-name as an argument, so in my case, the chain name would be `PREROUTING`.

Also according to `iptables --help`:

```
--list-rules -S [chain [rulenum]]
Print the rules in a chain or all chains
```

But what I get is:

```
$ iptables -S PREROUTING
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables -S REDIRECT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

How can I actually print the forwarding rule that I created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PREROUTING` chain is in the NAT table (`iptables -t nat`) so that's what you need to list in order to see it

```
iptables -t nat -nvL
```

You can generalise this for all four tables

```
for table in filter mangle nat raw
do
    echo
    echo "Rules for table $table"
    echo
    iptables -t "$table" --line-numbers -nvL
done
```